# Deleted elementaryOS and can’t boot Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows

I have deleted elementaryOS from Windows Disk Management and now I can’t boot into Windows anymore and Linux is gone.

Getting grub error when booting..

I’ve still got a live elementary USB I can boot to, can I create a partition/resize my windows disk from here, then reinstall elementary and remove in the correct manner? Or can I just remove the grub boot loader from here?

Would like to keep the existing Windows data ideally..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your disk setup (MBR/UEFI), you may want to try one of [these](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows) solutions. (Read the answers to choose the best strategy.)